# calculating column sum for certain row

Tags: r, sum

I am trying to calculate column sum of per 5 rows for each row, in R using the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(count=1:10)

for (loop in (1:nrow(df)))
{df[loop,"acc_sum"] <- sum(df[max(1,loop-5):loop,"count"])}
```

But I don't like the explicit loop here, how can I modify it? Thanks.

Comment: `zoo::rollsum(df$count,6, align="right", fill=NA)`

Comment: @Khashaa thank you,rollsum works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, your desired result is:

```
df
#    count acc_sum
# 1      1       1
# 2      2       3
# 3      3       6
# 4      4      10
# 5      5      15
# 6      6      21
# 7      7      27
# 8      8      33
# 9      9      39
# 10    10      45
```

This can be done like this:

```
df <- data.frame(count=1:10)

library(zoo)

df$acc_sum <- rev(rollapply(rev(df$count), 6, sum, partial = TRUE, align = "left"))
```

To obtain this result, we are reversing the order of `df$count`, we sum the elements (using `partial = TRUE` and `align = "left"` is important here), and we reverse the result to have the vector needed.

```
rev(rollapply(rev(df$count), 6, sum, partial = TRUE, align = "left"))
# [1]  1  3  6 10 15 21 27 33 39 45
```

Note that this sums 6 elements, not 5. According to the code in your question, this gives the same output. If you just want to sum 5 rows, just replace the 6 with a 5.